# Image map on mouse over show div

Tags: jquery, imagemap, onmouseover

So I am trying to create multiple image maps on a picture and then based on the image you are hovering over it will pull that specific information from a div that is below the picture and populate it next to the hovered over image.

```
<div class="runner_div">
  <img src="http://cooleycollective.com/test/slrc/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Em_full.jpg" width="680" height="705" usemap="#runner_wear" /></a></p>
<map name="runner_wear">
  <area shape="poly" coords="264,18,237,33,243,72,276,83,328,79,311,29," href="#hat" alt="hat"  />
  <area shape="rect" coords="259,69,331,99" href="#" alt="glasses" />

  </map>
</div>

<div class="gear" id=hat>
<h2>Type of hat</h2>
  <p>I love this hat.I wore it when I was running from a bear in the zoo.</p>
</div>
<div class="gear" id="glasses">
  <p>These glasses were hand picked by a Sherpa from Kentucy!</p>
</div>
```

I want the divs to stay below, so as to not be hidden, but also to have the functionality to be hoverable when I hover over the image it references.  I am not sure if I need to use jQuery for this or even how to create that code.

I feel like the code would do something like: onmouse hover of this imgmap then display the div that this imagemap references.  I have no idea what this would look like in code language.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want the popup effet.

[Please see a demo I've prepared for you using your markup](http://jsfiddle.net/LwQxR/)

Here's the working jQuery

```
var $popup = $('.popup');
$('area').on({
  mouseover : function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        $obj = $('#'+$this.prop('alt'));

    $popup.text($obj.text()).css({
      top: e.pageY + 25,
      left: e.pageX - ($popup.width()/2),
    }).show();
  },
  mouseout: function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $obj = $('#'+$this.prop('alt'));    

    $popup.hide(0).empty();
  }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work in wordpress and it isn't working.  It also messes up another script I am running for a slider.  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: @Tim Cooley Please show me what the error is so I can check it. It sounds like the global `$` variable, but we can check if it's something else.

Comment: I can't seem to find the error.  here is the site it is on.  Maybe you can see something I can't. http://cooleycollective.com/test/slrc/emily-cooleys-gear/

Comment: The above code looks like it works fine, the issues you're having are related to the files responding with a `404` error, which means `not found`. The link to the file location is incorrect. Please check the path and try again. There are 2 files, `slides.min.jquery.js`, and `jquery.easing.js`; both of these are missing.

Comment: Ok thanks I can just reference those with <script> tags?  and it should work?

Comment: @Tim Cooley Two methods in wordpress: Add them to the `head` file, or create a file called `functions.php` and add [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: Awesome :) - you may want to replace popup.tex obj.text with popup.html obj.htm, otherwise your HTML tags will be removed and only text will be shown